# User-proofing ListView StandardSetController getSelected from unsortable first column

Tags: encryption, standardsetcontroller

*(SFDC Classic)*

Given ListView VF page/controller invoked by a ListView button

**PAGE**

```
<apex:page id="thePage" standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactsCtrl" 
           recordSetVar="contacts">    
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:dataTable value="{!selectedContacts}" var="c"/>    
</apex:page>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public with sharing class ContactsCtrl {

    ApexPages.StandardSetController ssCtrl;

    public Contact[] selectedContacts {
        get {return (Contact[]) ssCtrl.getSelected();}
    }

    public ContactsCtrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController ssCtrl) {
        this.ssCtrl = ssCtrl;
    }
}
```

**If the ListView first column is an unsortable field**, e.g.

- A Platform-encrypted field *(our org; sad)*
- A multi-select picklist field

Then you will get at runtime this ugly VF page error

> core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesHandledException: Object type not accessible. Please check permissions and make sure the object is not in development mode: '003q000000w34tTAAQ') ) ) ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 10000 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:149 field 'Name' can not be sorted in a query call. Original queryString was: 'SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, Id FROM Contact WHERE ( ((OwnerId = '00536000004Ui8M')) AND (id IN ('003q000000w34spAAA','003q000000w34tTAAQ') ) ) ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 10000'

**If the first column of the ListView is a sortable field, the page displays fine.**

> So, how to protect against this as you have no control over the ordering of ListView columns?

**Option 1 - try and catch the exception**. No go, exception is uncatchable

**Option 2 - Get the selected Ids into the controller**

(and then do your own SOQL orderBy) without doing a `getSelected()` method. I can't see any way to do this

**Option 3 Convert ListView button to Javascript with Ajax Toolkit**

Aside from not being future-proofed for Lightning, does `{!GETRECORDIDS}`  end up under the covers doing a SOQL call with OrderBy that will throw the same issue above? Since being on VF is old enough, going back to Ajax Toolkit is ... enough said.

**Option 4 - Tell users not to create ListViews with unsortable fields as column 1**

...Hardly scalable

**Reference:**

[Known Issue NO FIX item](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4ubAAC)

[Platform Encryption Deterministic Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5)